Identify IC marked "AC"
What is the IC marked "AC" in the picture below?


all on its lonesome like that with only a capacitor for company,  probably a logic gate   74xx1Gxx

It's a Nexperia 74AHC1G04G inverter.


(Source: lcsc.com)
